# Structured data not working right with CSS selectors (adding slashes in links and other problems). How do I fix this?

Tags: html, schema, google-tag-manager, markup, structured-data

I work for a website with 10000+ products and I decided to input the structured data dynamically via **CSS selectors in GTM** because doing it manually would be too time consuming. It all worked fine, but then I ran into some problems.

Firstly, the structured data added slashes to links that lead to a 404, like so:

```
"url": "https:\/\/example.com\/shop\/category\/subcategory\/product"
```

Secondly, the prices in my country are separated with a comma, and not a dot, so the rich results test returns an error. Is there a way to change this?

Full schema here.

```
    <script type="application/ld+json"> {
       "@context": "https://www.schema.org",
       "@type": "product",
       "sku": "{{sku}}",
       "image": ["{{carousel-item active}}"],
       "name": "{{product-title}}",
       "description": "{{product-description}}",
       "category": "{{category}}",
       "brand": {
          "@type": "brand",
          "name": "BRAND",
          "logo": "https://example.com/images/logo.png"
          },
       "offers": {
          "@type": "Offer",
          "itemCondition": "http://schema.org/NewCondition",
          "availability": "http://schema.org/InStock",
          "price": "{{price}}",
          "priceValidUntil": "2021-11-11",
          "priceCurrency": "HRK",
          "url": "{{Page URL}}",
          "shippingDetails": {
                "@type": "OfferShippingDetails",
                "shippingRate": {
                           "@type": "MonetaryAmount",
                            "value": "25",
                            "currency": "HRK"
                            },
                "shippingDestination": {
                            "@type": "DefinedRegion",
                            "addressCountry": "HR"
                            },
                "deliveryTime": {
                            "@type": "ShippingDeliveryTime",
                            "transitTime": {
                                  "@type": "QuantitativeValue",
                                  "minValue": "3",
                                  "maxValue": "5"
                                  },
                "cutOffTime": "17:00-08:00",
                "businessDays": {
                            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                            "dayOfWeek": [ 
                                "https://schema.org/Monday",
                                "https://schema.org/Tuesday",
                                "https://schema.org/Wednesday",
                                "https://schema.org/Thursday",
                                "https://schema.org/Friday" ]
                                }
                            }
                      }
                 }
           }
    }
    </script>
```

I am *very* new to this, so please be gentle.

P.S. All other parts of schema work fine.

Comment: Those back slashes should be fine. They are just escaping the forward slash. When a parser reads the json-ld it will convert the URLs back to working ones. Try it with a testing tool like the Rich Results Tester.

Comment: @TonyMcCreath It says "Bad escape sequence in string" but only for the image url, and not the page url even though they look the same. 

The image URL looks like this:
"https:\/\/example.com\/imager\/418x418\/upload\/download\/1_s07.jpg?resize\x3d1"

So it is the same.

But I tried with choosing the full image which has a path like this:
"/upload/media/1_s07.jpg"

It works like this, but I don't know if spiders know what this is without the domain (example.com/upload/media/1_s07.jpg). 

Also, what about the price, is this a problem?

Comment: It would help to have the resulting json-ld that ends up on the page. Or even better, the URL that has the issue.